# How to deploy a git repo to multiple locations at once

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, express, deployment

I have developed a Node project related to school management. I have many schools who will be using this application.

For each school this application will be hosted on different servers. I am looking for a way to deploy updates on each server at once.

I have no experience with deployment and this is my first time doing something like this: what do I need to configure in order to make such a deployment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, assuming the remote repositories are bare (without checked out working tree), you can [push to multiple repositories in one `git push` command](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242)

```
cd /path/to/my/repository
git remote add all /url/first/remote/repo
git remote set-url --add --push all /url/second/remote/repo
git remote set-url --add --push all /url/third/remote/repo
...
```

Then git push all would push everywhere.

But a "git repository" in itself is not "deployed".
You need post-receive hook on the remote repositories in order to execute commands and actually deploy your application.
As an example of such hooks, see [`chovy/git-deploy-node`](https://github.com/chovy/git-deploy-node).

Comment: right now I have the git in one location on heroku, I think heroku takes care of all the deployment commands.

Comment: can I add ass many remotes as I like or is there a limit

Comment: @AmanMishra No limit that I know of, but start small, to test it out first.